# Android - Firebase not writing to database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having the worst luck attempting to resolve this. I have a project syced and successfully registering users to my Firebase project, but I cannot write to the Database following the official guide. The strangest thing is that the code I am using works on my friend's machine, but not on mine. I even created a new Firebase project and added the new google-services JSON file. After this, I was still able to sign up new users to the new Firebase project, but no luck on writing to the database. I'm at a loss and my friend thinks it might be best to un-install and re-install Android Studio. Anyone else encountered this issue?

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference locationReference = database.getReference("location");
locationReference.setValue(new Location(1234123, 1234323));
```

In this case, I am creating a new Location POJO and trying to save this object down with a dummy Lat Long.

Comment: what about your database rules ?

Comment: All set to read/write true.

Comment: That specific code looks fine, so is not likely the cause of your problems. Are there any warning or error messages in your logcat when you run this code? Can you *read* from the database?

Comment: In which place from your activity are you using this code? Can you share more code? Can you read from the database?

Comment: I resolved! I believe it was something with my configuration. I accidentally used the Firestore instead of the Realtime DB. Even though I changed it, I couldn't write to the DB. I created a new FB project and linked that.